# IBM quantum composer possible bug?(state amplitudes of quantum circuit)

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

I have this quantum circuit:

[image]

and from the IBM quantum composer I get this state amplitudes:

I wanted to flip the target qubit and keep only its pure state however this is not what I am getting.I am also getting the control qubit to be in state $|1>$ which I dont think is correct since the measurement gate doesnt do that.Is this a bug on the IBM quantum composer or is it due to how it treats a quantum circuit?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *measurement gate*?

Comment: The irreversible gate of measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug.Thats why you never simulate qubits on a classical computer.It translates the measurement gate into 1 or at least it shows only the 1:
[image]

It is 100% pure state so it is correct.